# How to embed four YouTube videos (16:9 responsive) in a 2x2 grid that can become a 1x4 grid depending on screen size?

Tags: html, css, responsive, embed, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to embed four YouTube videos in an HTML page with limited real estate. Depending on screen size, I'd like to have them arranged in a 2x2 grid, but collapsible into a 1x4 grid should screen size not permit it. I'm also trying to make the video size responsive in a 16:9 aspect ratio, with minimum and maximum sizes.

The closest I got was using some code from researching the Web, and this site. However, whatever I find, I can't seem to achieve my entire goal. Either I'm able to have the grid 2x2 collapsible into a 1x4, but I lose the embed aspect ratio and margins. Or I can get a 1x4 grid only with margins, but the wider the screen gets, the more space there is in between the videos because of the padding-bottom: 56.25%. Here's my latest attempt :

```
.vid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  }

.vid-cell {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    margin: 10px;
}

.vid-cell embed, iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    max-height: 315px;
    max-width: 560px;
}
```

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="vid-container">
<div class="vid-cell"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/somevid1"></iframe></div>
<div class="vid-cell"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/somevid2"></iframe></div>
<div class="vid-cell"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/somevid3"></iframe></div>
<div class="vid-cell"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/somevid4"></iframe></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](https://donald.net.au/bugs/so-76519132.html) the kind of effect you want? If not, please edit your question to make your requirements clearer.

(The code is shown below. I created a [test page](https://donald.net.au/bugs/so-76519132.html) rather than a snippet because YouTube embeds don’t work properly in a snippet.)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  margin: 1em;
}
.vid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  gap: 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .vid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="vid-container">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NXN33_E-R3k" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5gMa8Fcgoc4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2-BMxNC8cD8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xmeS2CTGSgs" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```